# Suggestion for building portal with smart plug

Tags: iot, ifttt

I am trying to build a Web portal that can get the details of power consumption from the smart plug and for i have [DLINK DSP W215 Plug](http://www.dlink.co.in/products/?pid=696) and i want to fetch the data from this device to my own web portal and perform some actions and also use the functionalities of the device using my web portal.
Please Suggest How is this possible. How can i connect with it.